# Подсчет количества товаров в корзине на Vanilla javascript?

Tags: javascript, cart

Есть корзина для магазина, которая выводит все товары добавленные в корзину, а нужно вывести всю сумму товаров в корзине. Используется такой код:

```
function addIntoCart(course){
const row= document.createElement('tr');
row.innerHTML= ` 
<tr>
<td>
<img src="${course.image}" width=100>
</td>
<td> ${course.title} </td>
<td> ${course.price} </td>
<td> <a href ="#" class="remove" data-id="${course.id}">X</a> </td>

</tr>

`;
shoppingCartContent.appendChild(row);

saveIntoStorage(course);}
```

Как добавить подсчет суммы?

Comment: сколько штук единиц это наверно course.length;  а количество посчитать course.price через reduce

Comment: Спасибо!  Попробую реализивать.

Comment: tr внутри innerHTML лишний... createElement и так создает tr. А количество будет таким: `console.log( shoppingCartContent.querySelectorAll("tr").length )` - после appendChild.